# Query in prolog

Tags: prolog

I know about that we can add facts dynamic at run time, mean

`fact1(+First,+Second).`

I can insert using asserta. But I want to ask can i add the functor at run time mean initially there is only a single fact like `fact1(first,second).` but user will insert some more facts at run time say

`fact2(first,second).`
`fact3(first,second).`

Here initially we don't know how many facts are to be added. Say user will give input as 3 then we have to add fact1,fact2 and fact3. If user gives input as 4 then we have to add four fact i.e. fact1,fact2,fact3 and fact4.

Any suggestions in this direction are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build the fact to assert using the predicates atom_concat/3 and =../2
Here goes an example that uses these to assert a predicate as you need (a base name, a number and two arguments):

```
assert_predicate(Name, N, Parm1, Parm2):-
  atom_concat(Name, N, FactName),
  Fact=..[FactName, Parm1, Parm2],
  asserta(Fact).
```

and you would use it with something like:
  assert_predicate(fact, 1, first, second)